# React Native Dynamically Bind Picker to list of Picker.Item Error

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am really new to React Native. When I try to bind Picker dynamically. For an item with data from the API, the error

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...marka_arr.map...')]

is shown. I believe the reason is before getting data, and it tries to render Picker. Can you help me to fix the error?

Code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';


const VeriGuncelleme = ({route}) => {
    
    const { responseData } = route.params;
    const {kullaniciBilgisi} = route.params;


    var bolge = responseData.items[0].bolge; 
    var etiket_no = responseData.items[0].etiket_no;
    var marka = responseData.items[0].uretici;
    var model = responseData.items[0].model;
    var serino = responseData.items[0].serino;
    var ad_soyad = responseData.items[0].ad_soyad;
    var varlik_turu = responseData.items[0].varlik_turu;


    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("");
    const url_marka = --here api url-- +varlik_turu;

    var marka_arr_new=[];
    const [marka_arr, setMarkaArr] = useState([model]);

      axios.get(url_marka) 
      .then(res => {
         

        for(var i =0; i<res.data.items.length; i++){
          marka_arr_new.push(res.data.items[i].d);
        }
    
        setMarkaArr({marka_arr:marka_arr_new});
        
      })

    
    
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
           <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', padding:8}}>Etiket No        :  {etiket_no}</Text>
           <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', padding:8}}>Marka             :</Text>
           <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', padding:8}}>Model             :</Text>
           <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', padding:8}}>Seri No           :</Text>
           <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold', padding:8}}>Bölge              :</Text>

        </View>
        <View>

          <Picker
            selectedValue={selectedValue}
            style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}>

            { marka_arr.map((value,index) => {
                 return <Picker.item label={value} value={value} key ={index}/>}) }   

          </Picker>   
  
        </View>
    </View>
    );
  }
export default VeriGuncelleme;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container_style_two: {
      //marginTop:"5%",
      padding:40,
  },
  textOnay: {
    fontWeight:'bold', 
    padding:8,
    color:'green'
  },
  textOnaylanmadi: {
    fontWeight:'bold', 
    padding:8,
    color:'red'
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 40,
    flexDirection:"row"
    //alignItems: "center"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `setMarkaArr({marka_arr:marka_arr_new})` by `setMarkaArr(marka_arr_new)`.

`{ marka_arr:marka_arr_new }` is an object, not an array. So the `.map` function is not available in Object.

Comment: Thank you sir. I replaced it as you say and it is worked.